# How to measure memory bandwidth utilization on Windows?

Tags: windows, performance, profiling

I have a highly threaded program but I believe it is not able to scale well across multiple cores because it is already saturating all the memory bandwidth.

Is there any tool out there which allows to measure how much of the memory bandwidth is being used?

**Edit**: Please note that typical profilers show things like memory leaks and memory allocation, which I am not interested in. 
I am only whether the memory bandwidth is being saturated or not.

Comment: If you want a sysadmin tool, you need to specify your OS. of you want a programmatic tool, you need to specify the programming language.

Comment: Actually, no. Memory bandwidth out of the CPU through caches to main meory is a low-level concept _entirely_ independent of programming language.

Comment: its windows.
i edited the title to reflect this.
agree with msalters, programming language has nothing to do with memory bandwidth measurement.

Comment: By 'programmatic tool', I meant that you might have wanted to include it into your own code rather than run it as a separate application. I should have made myself clearer.

Comment: It seems very, very unlikely that you can measure memory bandwidth utilisation.  You can measure memory bandwidth of course, but you couldn't measure it while other apps are running then expect the difference between the two values to be the used memory bandwidth.  Unless there's something built into the CPU, or memory controller, then you can't do this.  I've never heard of it..

Comment: @KierenJohnstone well, seems like "very, very unlikely" is not that unlikely after all. See the answer by Roman below... ;)

Answer (score 11):

If you have a recent Intel processor, you might try to use Intel(r) Performance Counter Monitor: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-performance-counter-monitor/ It can directly measure consumed memory bandwidth from the memory controllers.

Comment: any chance there is a tool that consumes this data and prints it out?

Comment: Intel Performance Counter Monitor is discontinued. Instead, they contribute updates and new features to the fork Processor Counter Monitor on github: https://github.com/opcm/pcm.

Comment: Is there an equivalent for AMD Ryzen CPUs?

Comment: @usertest - https://www.hwinfo.com/

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend the Visual Studio Sample Profiler which can collect sample events on specific hardware counters.  For example, you can choose to sample on cache misses.  [Here's an article explaining how to choose the CPU counter](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/profiler/archive/2010/06/22/cpu-performance-counters-in-visual-studio-2010-profiler.aspx), though there are other counters you can play with as well.

Answer (score 2):

it would be hard to find a tool that measured memory bandwidth utilization for your application.

But since the issue you face is a suspected memory bandwidth problem, you could try and measure if your application is generating a lot of page faults / sec, which would definitely mean that you are no where near the theoretical memory bandwidth.

You should also measure how cache friendly your algorithms are. If they are thrashing the cache, your memory bandwidth utilization will be severely hampered. Google "measuring cache misses" on good sources that tells you how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to properly measure memory bus utilisation with any kind of software-only solution. (it used to be, back in the 80's or so. But then we got piplining, cache, out-of-order execution, multiple cores, non-uniform memory architectues with multiple busses, etc etc etc).

You absolutely have to have hardware monitoring the memory bus, to determine how 'busy' it is.

Fortunately, most PC platforms do have some, so you just need the drivers and other software to talk to it:

wenjianhn comments that there is a project specficially for intel hardware (which they call the Processor Counter Monitor) at https://github.com/opcm/pcm

For other architectures on Windows, I am not sure. But there is a project (for linux) which has a grab-bag of support for different architectures at https://github.com/RRZE-HPC/likwid

In principle, a computer engineer could attach a suitable oscilloscope to almost any PC and do the monitoring 'directly', although this is likely to require both a suitably-trained computer engineer as well as quite high performance test instruments (read: both very costly).

If you try this yourself, know that you'll likely need instruments or at least analysis which is aware of the protocol of the bus you're intending to monitor for utilisation.

This can sometimes be really easy, with some busses - eg old parallel FIFO hardware, which usually has a separate wire for 'fifo full' and another for 'fifo empty'.

Such chips are used usually between a faster bus and a slower one, on a one-way link. The 'fifo full' signal, even it it normally occasionally triggers, can be monitored for excessively 'long' levels: For the example of a USB 2.0 Hi-Speed link, this happens when the OS isn't polling the USB fifo hardware on time. Measuring the frequency and duration of these 'holdups' then lets you measure bus utilisation, but only for this USB 2.0 bus.

For a PC memory bus, I guess you could also try just monitoring how much power your RAM interface is using - which perhaps may scale with use. This might be quite difficult to do, but you may 'get lucky'. You want the current of the supply which feeds VccIO for the bus. This should actually work much better for newer PC hardware than those ancient 80's systems (which always just ran at full power when on).

A fairly ordinary oscilloscope is enough for either of those examples - you just need one that can trigger only on 'pulses longer than a given width', and leave it running until it does, which is a good way to do 'soak testing' over long periods.

You monitor utiliation either way by looking for the change in 'idle' time.

But modern PC memory busses are quite a bit more complex, and also much faster.

To do it directly by tapping the bus, you'll need at least an oscilloscope (and active probes) designed explicitly for monitoring the generation of DDR bus your PC has, along with the software analysis option (usually sold separately) to decode the protocol enough to figure out the kind of activity which is occuring on it, from which you can figure out what kind of activity you want to measure as 'idle'.

You may even need a motherboard designed to allow you to make those measurements also.

This isn't so staightfoward as just looking for periods of no activity - all DRAM needs regular refresh cycles at the very least, which may or may not happen along with obvious bus activity (some DRAM's do it automatically, some need a specific command to trigger it, some can continue to address and transfer data from banks not in refresh, some can't, etc).

So the instrument needs to be able to analyse the data deeply enough for you extract how busy it is.

Your best, and simplest bet is to find a PC hardware (CPU) vendor who has tools which do what you want, and buy that hardware so you can use those tools.

This might even involve running your application in a VM, so you can benefit from better tools in a different OS hosting it.

To this end, you'll likely want to try Linux KVM (yes, even for Windows - there are windows guest drivers for it), and also pin down your VM to specific CPUs, whilst you also configure linux to avoid putting other jobs on those same CPUs.

Answer (score -1):

https://www.hwinfo.com/ supports this for some modern CPUs that report those metrics

[image]